# pandas group by project and sort within groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I output a groupby object to a csv file? 
My original input tsv file has the following format:

```
id     score    domain
1       5         x
2       3         x
1       4         y
2       2         y
```

I need the output tsv file to be grouped by id and sorted by score (descending order) so it will look like this:

```
id      score     domain
1        5          x
1        4          y
2        3          x
2        2          y
```

Any suggestions how should I do that? I tried some groupby and sort_values functions using pandas but it did not produce the required output for me. Thanks!

Comment: `df=df.sort_values(['id','score'],ascending=[True,False])`

Comment: How can I limit to only the highest score entry for each id then? like
id    score    domain
1       5           x
2       3           x

Comment: You can take advantage of the fact that it's already sorted and then just group and call head. After Wen's solution just do `df.groupby('id').head(1)`

Comment: @yuhengd after sort, drop_duplicate keep= first